# Fazer o dropdown do Bootstrap fechar ao clicar em outro dropdown no mesmo menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown

O menu precisa permanecer aberto enquanto eu clico em qualquer lugar do documento ou da tela, porém, quando eu clicar no dropdown de um segundo menu, ele deve fechar o anterior, e também precisa abrir e fechar clicando no dropdown.

**Meu código do bootstrap:**

```
 $(function() {
    $('.dropdown.opened')
    .on({
        "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { 
            this.closable = ($('.dropdown.open').length > 1) ? true : false 
         },
        "click":             function() { this.closable = true; 
        if (($('.dropdown.open').length > 1)) {
           $('.dropdown.opened').removeClass('open');
          }

        },
        "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
    });
 });
```

Veja que na regra estou verificando se existe ao menos 1 aberto, então ele muda o comportamento, de dropdown, porém ele deveria fechar todos os menus quando eu clico em outro qualquer ou no mesmo dropdown, e começar o processo de dropdown novamente.

[**Veja o menu no JSIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/1Lgkbget/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já resolvi o problema, bastou fazer um trigger no botão:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown.opened')
    .on({
        "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { 
            this.closable = ($('.dropdown.open').length > 1) ? true : false 
         },
        "click":             function() { this.closable = true; 
        $('.dropdown.opened.open').trigger('click');

        },
        "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução: Remover a verificação `if (($('.dropdown.open').length > 1))`

```
$(function() {

$('.dropdown.opened')
.on({
    "shown.bs.dropdown": function() { this.closable = ($('.dropdown.open').length > 1) ? true : false },
    "click":             function() { this.closable = true; 
       $('.dropdown.opened').removeClass('open');

    },
    "hide.bs.dropdown":  function() { return this.closable; }
})

});
```

[**Veja o menu no JSIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/1Lgkbget/4/)

Comment: Segue [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/1Lgkbget/4/) com sua alteração caso queira adicionar a resposta e +1 :)

Comment: Não @Brunno, o dropdown não está fechando, isso não soluciona o problema...

Comment: Você só deixou ele travado... Não é isso que preciso, preciso que o menu seja "dropdown", ou seja, quando clico nele 1ª vez abre e na 2ª vez ele fecha. Eu editei a pergunta para ficar mais claro, ok?

Answer (score -1):

Como parâmetro do removeClass deve ser passado a string 'opened'. Se você remover a classe 'open', ele irá ficar travado. Segue o fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1Lgkbget/6/

(Alterei do nosso amigo acima)